# beautiful soup bug?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have next code:

```
for table in soup.findAll("table","tableData"):
    for row in table.findAll("tr"):
        data = row.findAll("td")
        url = data[0].a
        print type(url)
```

I get next output:

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

That means, that url is object of class Tag and i could get attribytes from this objects.
But if i replace `print type(url)` to `print url['href']` i get next traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "baseCreator.py", line 57, in <module>
    createStoresTable()
File "baseCreator.py", line 46, in createStoresTable
    print url['href']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What is wrong? And how i can get value of href attribute.

Comment: You have a loop; are you sure *all* tr > td elements have a `<a/>` tag?

Comment: That error means that the url that it fails on is None. Try running it with `if url:` `print url['href']`.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Page contain very big table with urls in every row. But when i looked carefuly i found that in one row url is missing.

Answer (score 2):

I do like `BeautifulSoup` but I personally prefer `lxml.html` (for not too *wacky* HTML) because of the ability to utilise XPath.

```
import lxml.html
page = lxml.html.parse('http://somesite.tld')
print page.xpath('//tr/td/a/@href')
```

Might need to implement some form of "axes" though depending on the structure.

You can also use `elementsoup` as a parser - details at http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html

Comment: lxml also has a beautifulsoup backend.

Comment: @Marcin Good point, I forgot to mention about soupparser - updated, with thanks.